# puppet can't apply; Error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have an issue getting puppet to work. I'm working on OpenSUSE 13.2, my ruby version is 2.1.3p242 and the puppet version is 3.7.1.

I got the `site.pp` for testing puppet:

```
node default {

file { '/tmp/depl_mon.sql':
  ensure  => file,
  content => 'CREATE TABLE if not exists hash_key (id varchar(64) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));',
}

}
```

And here is the error I get when I run `puppet apply site.pp --trace --debug`:

```
Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=3.7.1, ruby_version=2.1.3, run_mode=user, default_encoding=UTF-8
Error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:19:in `compile'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puppet-4.3.0/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/util/profiler/around_profiler.rb:58:in `profile'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/util/profiler.rb:51:in `profile'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puppet-4.3.0/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:91:in `block in compile'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/util.rb:161:in `block in benchmark'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/util.rb:160:in `benchmark'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puppet-4.3.0/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:90:in `compile'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puppet-4.3.0/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:50:in `find'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:201:in `find'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/application/apply.rb:217:in `block in main'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/context.rb:64:in `override'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet.rb:244:in `override'
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/application/apply.rb:193:in `main'                                                                                                        
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/application/apply.rb:154:in `run_command'                                                                                                 
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/application.rb:384:in `block (2 levels) in run'                                                                                           
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/application.rb:510:in `plugin_hook'                                                                                                       
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/application.rb:384:in `block in run'                                                                                                      
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/util.rb:488:in `exit_on_fail'                                                                                                             
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/application.rb:384:in `run'                                                                                                               
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/util/command_line.rb:146:in `run'                                                                                                         
/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/puppet/util/command_line.rb:92:in `execute'                                                                                                      
/usr/bin/puppet:8:in `<main>'
```